# Forms and Subforms in Access 2003

Tags: ms-access

I have only **one** table and I would like to create a form for the users to populate the table easily.  There are at least 5 fields in the table that only needs to be completed if a certain type of inspection (Fire) is selected from a drop down list and is left blank otherwise.

I would like to create a subform that will only pop up when inspection type "Fire" is selected from the drop down list in the main form.  How can I do this?

I used the wizard to create the form and I am stuck because I really don't know VBA.  So far, I went to the **inspection type** field on the form, clicked on "Properties", then clicked on "After Update", then selected the Macro that I created to open the subform when the **inspection type = "Fire"**, but it isn't working.

What happens is the subform gets opened up no matter what type of inspection I select, then the ID number on the subform doesn't correspond to the main form (the subform ID will remain on id#1). Also, when I do input data in the subform, the information ends in the next record.

I was wondering if that is happening because I am using both the form and the subform to enter data into the same table. I hope this is a clear explanation of what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just to try to improve a bit on Kovags excellent proposition:

```
Sub InspectionType_AfterUpdate
    Subform1.Visible=(InspectionType.Text="Fire")
End Sub

Sub Form_Current
    InspectionType_AfterUpdate
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Your code also worked well but now I have to figure out how to close the subform after the last entry is made and make sure that the inputted info has been saved

Comment: In Access a record is automatically saved when you quit the record.

Comment: If you really want to force it, use If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False

Answer (score 0):

Just change this code to adapt your needs and add it to the Change Event of the Inspection Type textbox:

```
Sub InspectionType_Change
  if InspectionType.Text="Fire" Then
    Subform1.Visible=True
  else
    Subform1.Visible=False
  endif
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me solve this problem.  The code is great and worked fine. Now I only have to figure out how make the subform disappear after the user has input the last item.  Thanks again

Comment: Why the CHANGE event instead of AfterUpdate?

Answer (score 0):

If the fields are on the same table then I'd suggest placing the fields on the subform onto the main form.  Then making them visible or not depending on the state of the combo box.

Using a subform gets a bit more complex as, among other things, you will need to save the record in the main form before opening the subform.  Otherwise the subform won't be able to update the record and will give you a locking message.

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this problem.  I also used your method in the following way:

Comment: `If Me!txtControl1 = "Fire" then`
    `Me!txtControl2.Visible = True`
     `Else`
     `Me!txtControl2.Visible = False`
End If

Comment: A simpler alterative to the code would be `(Me!txtControl2.Visible = Me!txtControl1 = "Fire")`.